# HLS: reading PRIV ID3 tag with com.apple.streaming.transportStreamTimestamp PTS time mark

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, aac, id3

I have a hls live stream where i can go back 30 minutes (timeshift):

I want to save a part of the 30 minutes window as mp4 file locally.

I parsed the playlist, downloaded the single ts and aac segments and have put them together (concatinate). The result is always asynchronous.

There is a timestamp in the ts segments but not in the aac segments. 
The timestamps of the aac segment are probably in a private id3 tag, but i don't know how i can read them.

Here is a good analysis:
https://github.com/flavioribeiro/nginx-audio-track-for-hls-module/issues/22

Does anyone have an idea how i can read that timestamp (OS: Linux)?

Comment: example: `wget https://sdn-global-live-streaming-packager-cache.3qsdn.com/6191/aac1811281007144892audio_1075.aac`

Comment: I can read it in hex: `exiftool -Private -b aac1811281007144892audio_1075.aac | hexdump -C`

Comment: I am trying this with a video transport stream (ts) and get a warning. Using -extractEmbedded instead of -Private.

Comment: @micha this reads the octets backwards e.g. a2 b3 -> 2a 3b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# get audio start from aac segment
# dump private id3 Tag
HEXDUMP=`exiftool -Private -b file.aac | od -t x8 --endian=big --address-radix=n | xargs echo -n`
# convert to decimal
DECIMAL=$((0x$HEXDUMP))
# it is an MPEG-2 Timestamp in 1/90000 Seconds, get it in seconds
AUDIOSTART=`expr $DECIMAL / 90000`
```